# Having a div remain below all the other divs on my page

Tags: css, html, center, margin

Right now I have something like this:

```
<div id="pagebody">
    <div id="left-entries"> </div>
    <div id="right-entries"> </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    ....text....
</div>
```

`left-entries` and `right-entries` have `float: left;`  so that they show up beside each other within `pagebody`.

`pagebody` has `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` so that it sits in the center.

How can I get `footer` to ALWAYS show up under `pagebody`? Right now it is positioned somewhat behind everything. I have a feeling it is because `pagebody` doesn't have a defined height (because the height is defined by what is inside it and that's variable depending on the content).

Any ideas?

Comment: tried `clear:both` on the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `clear:both;` to #footer it will always be below the pagebody

Comment: eh... I beat you both with my comment :P (am I the only one who sees stackoverflow as a competitive MMO? >_>)

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear it.

```
clear: both;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend clearing your floated DIV's. You can do this by adding a "clear" class any parent elements that contains any floated children. I think this works best, because it's less markup in your HTML. (via [Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/))

For example:

```
<style>
    .clear:before, .clear:after { content:""; display:table; }
    .clear:after { clear:both; }
    .clear { zoom:1; } /* IE 6/7 (hasLayout) */
</style>

<div id="pagebody" class="clear">
    <div id="left-entries"> </div>
    <div id="right-entries"> </div>
</div>
```

Should clear anything below the #pagebody DIV.